# how to find special character like \t \n \u and single quotation mark (") in presto

Tags: presto

I'm using presto. I have a table that contain address information. It has varchar format.

How do I find addresses that contain special characters like:

- `\t` (tab)
- `\n` (newline)
- `\u`
- single quotation mark (`'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LIKE` with literal containing newline. Convenient way it to use unicode escapes for this (newline `\n` is `U+000A` in Unicode):

```
col LIKE U&'%\000A%'
```

`U&'...'` creates string literal, just like `'...'`.
The only difference is that `U&'...'` supports `\hhhh` escapes for Unicode.

Example:

```
presto:default> SELECT 'abc
             -> def' LIKE U&'%\000A%';
 _col0
-------
 true
(1 row)
```

Tested on Presto 324.

Comment: You're welcome. I've created https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/2113 so that we document this. Also, I invite you to Presto Community Slack https://prestosql.io/slack.html if you have any questions that do not fit SO.