# Valid Representation of unicode Sequence in Java

Tags: java, string, unicode, escaping, presto

I have presto query that contains some Japanese characters in where clause

```
select col1  from xyz where col = '自社在庫' // example
```

for some reason i need to interpret this query  and do some validations, for this i am using the facebook presto sql parser .
But when i use `com.facebook.presto.sql.SqlFormatter.formatSql(sqlParsed, null);`
The returned String looks like this :

```
SELECT col1 FROM xyz WHERE (colr = **U&'\81EA\793E\5728\5EAB'**)
```

Should it not convert it as `select col1 from xyz where colr = '\u81EA\u793E\u5728\u5EAB'`

Any way i can convert U&'\81EA\793E\5728\5EAB' back to '自社在庫' ?

Comment: When parsing and validting, you actually do not change the query. Do you really have to serialize and come back to the original string? You should still have that available anyway...

Comment: [1] The conversion is correct with the exception of the pairs of asterisks, which I can't explain. If those are possibly typos in your question, please correct. Otherwise, the returned string is a valid Unicode string literal for Presto (aka Trino). See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59049533/2985643) and the issue [Document unicode varchar literals #2113](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/2113). [2] Are you asking if there's an API that will handle the conversion of the string, or just how to do it in Java?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the presto serializer does something different than you expect. I'd try to search for a solution within the presto library.

If that does not work, you could translate the string by stripping off the leading and trailing asterisks, then replace every `\` with `\u` and are back to your assumed result.